# Running a Gallery Shortcode in a Custom Fields Widget

Tags: custom-field, widgets, shortcode, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I am creating a website for a Fringe Adelaide Venue, we have planned on displaying a gallery on each artist page. We are already using Custom Fields to place some unique content in a Custom Fields widget that we are including on the page.

We have tried to place and execute the gallery shortcode inside of the Custom Fields widget, with no success. We need it to be in the widget so we can position it properly.
The theme is Gantry, I am able to change plugins if necessary, but not theme.

I have spent all day yesterday researching a solution and still have not succeeded.

EDIT: The Widget we are using for Custom Fields is [Custom Field Widget](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-field-widget/)

Cheers,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add this filter

```
<?php
 /**
 * Plugin Name: Shortcodes support for the Custom Fields Widget plugin
 *
 */    
add_filter( 'custom_field_value', 'do_shortcode' );
```

as a [plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

This should hopefully make your shortcodes work.

[Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) you can read more about the WordPress function `do_shortcode()`.

Comment: Where file should I add this filter to?

Comment: I would add this as a plugin, but you can test it by adding it to the functions.php file in your current theme directory.

Comment: Brilliant, that works great! I added that code to the plugin first and that worked...

Comment: great to hear that and welcome to WPSE ;-)